# add function to refresh applied filters on a button, function doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, button, refresh

html button

```
<button
  id="styleButton"
  class="ml-2 refreshButton"
  (click)="removeAllFilters(appliedFilters)"
>
<i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>
</button>
```

ts function

```
removeAllFilters() {
        this.appliedFilters = [];

        this.searchText = '';

        this.status.map(item => {
            if (item.name !== TypeStatus.ACTIVE) item.selected = false;
        });

        this.locations.map(item => (item.selected = false));

        this.roles.map(item => (item.selected = false));
    }
```

I tried to apply remove all filters function, but doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map method never edits the actual array. It just returns a new array that contains your modifications.

Therefore you have two alternatives to solve the problem;

**1. You can change `map` to `forEach`**

```
removeAllFilters() {
        this.appliedFilters = [];
        this.searchStaffText = '';
        this.status.forEach(item => {
            if (item.name !== StaffTypeStatus.ACTIVE) item.selected = false;
        });
        this.locations.forEach(item => (item.selected = false));
        this.roles.forEach(item => (item.selected = false));
    }
```

**2. You can reassign all the arrays to the modified ones that will be returned by `map` method.**

```
removeAllFilters() {
        this.appliedFilters = [];
        this.searchStaffText = '';
        this.status = this.status.map(item => {
            if (item.name !== StaffTypeStatus.ACTIVE) item.selected = false;
            return item;
        });
        this.locations = this.locations.map(item => {
            item.selected = false;
            return item;
        });
        this.roles = this.roles.map(item => {
            item.selected = false;
            return item;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all inside your html you call `removeAllFilters(appliedFilters)`. The param **appliedFilters** is not available inside your ts code.

Second: You use `map` wrong. Every map needs to `return` something. Example:

```
removeAllFilters() {
        this.appliedFilters = [];

        this.searchStaffText = '';

        this.status = this.status.map(item => {
            if (item.name !== StaffTypeStatus.ACTIVE) item.selected = false;
            return item; // IMPORTANT TO RETURN ANYTHING
        });

        this.location = this.locations.map(item => {
            item.selected = false;
            return item; // IMPORTANT TO RETURN ANYTHING
        });

        this.roles = this.roles.map(item => {
            item.selected = false;
            return item;
        });
    }
```

Greetings, Flo

Comment: even if you return the item in every iteration - the value of the array will not change - only if you assign the mapped value to a new one

Comment: Both answers were right, thank you very much :D